# Key-value union function ocaml

Tags: list, tuples, ocaml, union, key-value

I am trying to make a function that takes two lists of pairs with `(key,value)`, compares the key and if it is the same it returns a list of the union:
`[(1,["one"]);(1,["uno"])]` and  `[(2,["two"]);(1,["eden"])]`
should return `[(1,["one";"uno";"eden"]);(2,"two")]`
this code returns unit and I'm not sure why:

```
type 'a kvs=(int*('a list))list ;;
let rec union l1 l2 =  match l1 with 
  |[]->l2
  |h::t-> let (k1,v1) = h and (k2,v2)=(List.hd l2) in 
      if (k1=k2)then begin 
        v1@v2;     (*this part*)
        union t l2
      end 
      else union t l2;;

let l1 = [(1,["three"]);(1,["tri"])];;
let l2 = [(2,["three"]);(1,["tri"])];;
union l1 l2;;
```

Comment: Lists are immutable. `v1@v2` creates a new list, but you're just discarding it. You need to think about how you will return this value along with the result from calling `union` on the rest of the list.

Comment: Hey OP(@tacocat), since my answer got downvoted and I have no way to know why, so a little help I am expecting from you. Please leave me a comment if it is you who has downvoted so that I can know the reason for it and ignore if not. I don't care about the downvote as much but just trying to understand how to respond to questions which can be interpreted in multiple ways and can there be a way to respond which satisfies all the different and unrelated interpretation. Please help, I am urging only to make myself better at doing things on SO.

Comment: @NalinRanjan My guess is because you don't address the actual question. OP didn't just ask for a solution, but for an explanation of why they're getting an error. Although I'd argue that even if they did just ask for a solution you still shouldn't just give them a copy-and-paste answer, because most of these kinds of questions come from students trying to solve an exercise, and there's a good reason why professors create exercises rather than just post lists of example problems and solutions; to get students to think about _how_ to solve the problem and consider different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a little on the comment by @glennsl: when you use `stmt1; stmt2` the  result of of `stmt1` is discarded. The construct can be still useful if you use `stmt1` for its side effects. E.g. the function

```
let f x =
 Printf.printf "you passed the string %s" x;
 x
```

does not change its result but prints the string `x` as additional side effect. The warning you see is always emitted when `stmt1` does not have the type unit because you are implicitly disregarding its value. Instead, it's better to use the pattern

```
    let v = v1@v2 in
    union t l2
```

such that you can use `v` in the recursive call.

If you just want the warning to go away, you can always use `ignore(stmt1); stmt2` to silently discard the value of `stmt1` but in most cases this is not what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Under assumption that you want a function which gets you the desired output and the order is insignificant in the output, following is somewhat I think you need...

```
let union l1 l2 =
  let
    filter_unique = List.fold_left (fun acc curr -> if not (List.exists (fun y -> y = curr) acc) then (curr::acc) else acc) []
  in
  let rec unique_unions acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | ((key, value)::tail) ->
       try
         let existing_values = List.assoc key acc in
         unique_unions ((key, filter_unique (existing_values @ value)) :: (List.remove_assoc key acc)) tail
       with
         Not_found -> unique_unions ((key, value) :: acc) tail
  in    
  unique_unions [] (l1 @ l2)
```